# Github repository giving an error while building in PyCharm venv

Tags: python, cmake, pybind11, cmake-gui, cmake-modules

I am using Python wrapper for the first time.
I am working on Windows and I want to use this(https://gitlab.com/smeeze/eego-sdk-pybind11) repository in my PyCharm venv. While building it `cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release C:/User/mypath/PycharmProjects/eego-sdk-pybind11/`, I am getting the following error:

```
-- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.18362.0 to target Windows 10.0.18363.
-- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.18362.0 to target Windows 10.0.18363.
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:21 (ExternalProject_Add):
  Syntax error in cmake code at

    C:/Users/mypath/PycharmProjects/connect/_deps/eego_sdk-subbuild/CMakeLists.txt:22

  when parsing string

    C:\Users\mypath\PycharmProjects\eego-sdk-pybind11

  Invalid character escape '\U'.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

CMake Error at C:/Users/mypath/PycharmProjects/connect/venv/Lib/site-packages/cmake/data/share/cmake-3.27/Modules/FetchContent.cmake:1650 (message):
  CMake step for eego_sdk failed: 1
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Users/mypath/PycharmProjects/connect/venv/Lib/site-packages/cmake/data/share/cmake-3.27/Modules/FetchContent.cmake:1802:EVAL:2 (__FetchContent_directPopulate)
  C:/Users/mypath/PycharmProjects/connect/venv/Lib/site-packages/cmake/data/share/cmake-3.27/Modules/FetchContent.cmake:1802 (cmake_language)
  cmake/eego-sdk.cmake:9 (FetchContent_Populate)
  CMakeLists.txt:9 (include)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

While giving the following command `cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release C:/Users/mypath/PycharmProjects/eego-sdk-pybind11/` I have tried using `\\` and `/`, I also tried putting the path in double quotes. It gives the same error every time.

I don't know if this could be helpful-
I read the CMakeLists.txt file and there I found that the URL is saved like this `"C:\Users\mypath\PycharmProjects\eego-sdk-pybind11"`

```
include(ExternalProject)
ExternalProject_Add(eego_sdk-populate
                    "UPDATE_DISCONNECTED" "False" "EXTERNALPROJECT_INTERNAL_ARGUMENT_SEPARATOR" "URL" "C:\Users\mypath\PycharmProjects\eego-sdk-pybind11"
```

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: maybe it needs double escaping \\\\ instead of \\